# vaadin gui ,check box caption showing on left in formfieldfactory need to show on right

Tags: checkbox, caption, left-recursion

Create Field to add all required field need to add a check box "cb2" as well but the caption showing on right but I need to show it on left.

```
public Field createField(Item item, Object property, Component uiContext) {

        String pid = (String) property;

        if (pid.equals("group_id")) {
            try {
                groupofList = new GroupEntityContainer();

                groupofList = DA.getGroupList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "GroupEntityComboBox DataAccessContainer().getGroupList() failed " + e.getMessage());
            }

            Select select = new Select("User Role");

            if (groupofList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < groupofList.size(); i++) {
                    Collection<GroupEntity> ar = groupofList.getItemIds();
                    Iterator<GroupEntity> iterator = ar.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        GroupEntity c = iterator.next();
                        select.addItem(c.getGroup_id());
                        select.setItemCaption(c.getGroup_id(), c.getGroupname());
                    }
                }
                select.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
                select.setImmediate(true);
                return select;
            }
        }else if(pid.equals("apply_acess_control")){
             cb2=new CheckBox(pid);
            cb2.setEnabled(true);
            //cb2.setStyle("float:left");
            ValueChangeListener listner = new ValueChangeListener() {

                /**
                 * 
                 */


                @Override
                public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {


                    if(txndays !=null){
                    txndays.setEnabled((Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue());
                    //txndays.setValue(null);
                    }                    
                    //reengagementSelect.setVisible((Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue());
                }
            };
            cb2.addListener(listner);
            cb2.setImmediate(true);
           // cb2.setCaption("apply_acess_control");
            return cb2;
        } 
        else {
            TextField tx = new TextField(pid);
            if(pid.equals("inactivity_days"))
            {
                txndays= new TextField(pid);
                if(cb2.booleanValue())
                {
                    txndays.setEnabled(true);

                }else{
                txndays.setEnabled(false);
                txndays.setNullRepresentation("");
                }


                return txndays;
            }
            if (pid.equals("userPass"))
                // tx.setSecret(true);
                tx.setMaxLength(15);
            return tx;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

FormFieldFactory:-

```
public Field createField(Item item, Object property, Component uiContext) {

        String pid = (String) property;

        if (pid.equals("group_id")) {
            try {
                groupofList = new GroupEntityContainer();

                groupofList = DA.getGroupList();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "GroupEntityComboBox DataAccessContainer().getGroupList() failed " + e.getMessage());
            }

            Select select = new Select("User Role");

            if (groupofList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < groupofList.size(); i++) {
                    Collection<GroupEntity> ar = groupofList.getItemIds();
                    Iterator<GroupEntity> iterator = ar.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        GroupEntity c = iterator.next();
                        select.addItem(c.getGroup_id());
                        select.setItemCaption(c.getGroup_id(), c.getGroupname());
                    }
                }
                select.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
                select.setImmediate(true);
                return select;
            }
        }else if(pid.equals("apply_acess_control")){
             cb2=new CheckBox(pid);
            cb2.setEnabled(true);
            //cb2.setStyle("float:left");
            ValueChangeListener listner = new ValueChangeListener() {

                /**
                 * 
                 */


                @Override
                public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {


                    if(txndays !=null){
                    txndays.setEnabled((Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue());
                    //txndays.setValue(null);
                    }                    
                    //reengagementSelect.setVisible((Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue());
                }
            };
            cb2.addListener(listner);
            cb2.setImmediate(true);
           // cb2.setCaption("apply_acess_control");
            return cb2;
        } 
        else {
            TextField tx = new TextField(pid);
            if(pid.equals("inactivity_days"))
            {
                txndays= new TextField(pid);
                if(cb2.booleanValue())
                {
                    txndays.setEnabled(true);

                }else{
                txndays.setEnabled(false);
                txndays.setNullRepresentation("");
                }


                return txndays;
            }
            if (pid.equals("userPass"))
                // tx.setSecret(true);
                tx.setMaxLength(15);
            return tx;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Which Vaadin Version are you using? And if 10 or later do you use FormLayout?

Comment: I am using  vaadin6